# python - how to run background thread without stopping main thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

This simple code example:

```py
import threading
import time


class Monitor():

    def __init__(self):
        self.stop = False
        self.blocked_emails = []

    def start_monitor(self):
        print("Run start_monitor")
        rows = []
        while not self.stop:
            self.check_rows(rows)
            print("inside while")
            time.sleep(1)

    def check_rows(self, rows):
        print('check_rows')

    def stop_monitoring(self):
        print("Run stop_monitoring")
        self.stop = True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    monitor = Monitor()

    b = threading.Thread(name='background_monitor', target=monitor.start_monitor())
    b.start()
    b.join()

    for i in range(0, 10):
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Wait 2 sec.')
    monitor.stop_monitoring()
```

How can I run background thread, in mine case `background_monitor` without blocking main thread?

I wanted to `background_monitor` thread stopped on after `stop_monitoring` will be called

I mine example, the for loop from main thread never called and the background is running forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your current code. Firstly, you're calling `monitor.start_monitor` on this line, whereas according to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread)

> target is the callable object to be invoked by the run() method. Defaults to None, meaning nothing is called

This means that you need to pass it as a function rather than calling it. To fix this, you should change the line

```py
b = threading.Thread(name='background_monitor', target=monitor.start_monitor())
```

to

```py
b = threading.Thread(name='background_monitor', target=monitor.start_monitor)
```

which passes the function as an argument.

Secondly, you use [`b.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) before stopping the thread, which waits for the second thread to finish before continuing. Instead, you should place that below the `monitor.stop_monitoring()`.

The corrected code looks like this:

```py
import threading
import time


class Monitor():

    def __init__(self):
        self.stop = False
        self.blocked_emails = []

    def start_monitor(self):
        print("Run start_monitor")
        rows = []
        while not self.stop:
            self.check_rows(rows)
            print("inside while")
            time.sleep(1)

    def check_rows(self, rows):
        print('check_rows')

    def stop_monitoring(self):
        print("Run stop_monitoring")
        self.stop = True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    monitor = Monitor()

    b = threading.Thread(name='background_monitor', target=monitor.start_monitor)
    b.start()

    for i in range(0, 10):
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Wait 2 sec.')
    monitor.stop_monitoring()
    b.join()
```

Comment: I have changed code as you described but looks like nothing changed, I see only ```inside while``` as output. the text ```Wait 2 sec.``` doesn't appear

Comment: @Roman hmmmm... that's strange. It seems to work in my tests (https://repl.it/@minion3665/background-threads#main.py). Can you put up a link with your code (in repl.it or similar) so that I can try and see what's going wrong

Comment: Looks like I did something wrong last time. it works now. thanks